# Java How to list files with directory with pattern matcher

Tags: pattern-matching, filestream, filepath

The file structure is like the following:

```
root
 -- [anything]
   -- access.log
 -- [anything]
   -- access.log
```

path: /root/*/access.log

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    DirectoryScanner scanner = new DirectoryScanner();
    scanner.setIncludes(new String[]{"*/access.log"});
    scanner.setBasedir(basePath);
    scanner.scan();
    String[] files = scanner.getIncludedFiles();
```

This is the simplest solution using org.apache.tools.ant.DirectoryScanner